# ZipFile.isSplitArchive is returning false even though I set to true

Tags: java, junit, zip4j

```
        // Initiate ZipFile object with the path/name of the zip file.
        ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile("c:\\ZipTest\\CreateSplitZipFileFromFolder.zip");

        // Initiate Zip Parameters which define various properties such
        // as compression method, etc.
        ZipParameters parameters = new ZipParameters();

        // set compression method to store compression
        parameters.setCompressionMethod(Zip4jConstants.COMP_DEFLATE);

        // Set the compression level. This value has to be in between 0 to 9
        parameters.setCompressionLevel(Zip4jConstants.DEFLATE_LEVEL_NORMAL);

        // Create a split file by setting splitArchive parameter to true
        // and specifying the splitLength. SplitLenth has to be greater than
        // 65536 bytes
        // Please note: If the zip file already exists, then this method throws an 
        // exception
        zipFile.createZipFileFromFolder("C:\\ZipTest", parameters, true, 10485760);
```

I copied this from the sample code for using zip4j, specifically the file named `CreateSplitZipFileFromFolder.java`

the problem is that, even if I set to true the third parameter of `createZipFileFromFolder`, it would still return false when I call the method `ZipFile.isSplitArchive()`

from grepcode, it appears it just sets the `ZipModel` object the boolean flag that I set, but I get a different value. any ideas why this is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your generated ZIP file larger than `splitLength` bytes (10485760 in your example)? From the documentation of splitLength for [createZipFile](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.lingala.zip4j/zip4j/1.2.3/net/lingala/zip4j/core/ZipFile.java#ZipFile.createZipFile%28java.io.File%2Cnet.lingala.zip4j.model.ZipParameters%2Cboolean%2Clong%29)

> if archive has to be split, then length in bytes at which it has to be split

I assume a split Zip file will only be created if it gets larger than that size.

Comment: the answer was right in front of me, I was creating a zip file with size smaller than the split length. thank you